# How to select the element which has not combinations of classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. How can I hide only the divs which has not the classes as indicated in the `mopt[]`?

As you can see I am trying to show only two divs which has the `Q` and `M` classes but my code in hiding all of divs

```js
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
let mopt = ['Q','M']
for (i = 0; i < mopt.length; i++) {
   $(".box:not(:has(" + mopt[i] + "))").hide()
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: khaki;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>
```

Comment: You want to show those that have M **or** Q, or do you want to show those that have M **and** Q?

Comment: Though none of that will work with `:has()`, which checks for children.  http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: Hi Taplar , I am looking for all possible select of one to many. Only M, Only Q and MQ so 3 divs must be display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to hide boxes that have neither `Q` nor `M`, so you can filter on those that do not have `.Q, .M`, and hide those.

```js
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
let mopt = ['Q','M'];

$('.box').not(
  mopt.map(function(className){ return '.'+ className; }).join(', ')
).hide();
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: khaki;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this code..

```js
    
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
$(".box").not(".Q,.M").hide();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
      .box 
 {
         height: 20px;
          background: khaki;
   width: 100px;
          text-align:center;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
 <div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
 <div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
 <div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
 <div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
 <div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
 <div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```