# Selecting Element which Has Exact Combinations of Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already asked this question, somehow at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657154/issue-on-selecting-element-which-has-not-combinations-of-classes) but it comes out I was looking for wrong solution! My Bad!

As you can see I am looking for a solution to **ONLY** display the divs which has the combination of the array values. At this demo for example the output will be  3 divs as `Has Q`, `Has M`, and `Has Q & M` **BUT** I need to only display the `Has Q & M` which has all combination of array elements in the div

```js
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
let mopt = ['Q','M'];

$('.box').not(
  mopt.map(function(className){ return '.'+ className; }).join(', ')
).hide();
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: khaki;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> Should Display Only the Div which Has 'Q' <strong>AND </strong> 'M' together</h4>

<div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>

<p> but it is displaying all boxes which have part of `mopt` array</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When separating selectors with comma it will act as a [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) means each of them acts as a selector. To combine together concatenate them without any space.

```js
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
let mopt = ['Q','M'];

$('.box').not(
  mopt.map(function(className){ return '.'+ className; }).join('')
).hide();
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: khaki;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> Should Display Only the Div which Has 'Q' <strong>AND </strong> 'M' together</h4>

<div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>

<p> but it is displaying all boxes which have part of `mopt` array</p>
```

Refer :

[Selecting Elements | JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/)

[Simple Selectors | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

The way selectors work, is that you need to use the class name connected with a `.` in order to include multiple classes. So, for this example you would need `.Q.M`.

You can accomplish this with

```
'.' + mopt.join('.')
```

As seen below

```js
$('.A.W.B').css("background-color", "red");
let mopt = ['Q','M'];

$('.box').not(
  '.' + mopt.join('.')
).hide();
```

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: khaki;
  width: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> Should Display Only the Div which Has 'Q' <strong>AND </strong> 'M' together</h4>

<div class="box A B F  R W Q">Has Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B F W R M">Has M</div>
<div class="box A B F H K F">No Q</div>
<div class="box A B Q F H  M K F">Has Q & M</div>

<p> but it is displaying all boxes which have part of `mopt` array</p>
```